# Left shift of only part of a number

Tags: c, optimization, assembly, x86

I need to find the fastest equivalence of the following C code.

```
int d = 1 << x; /* d=pow(2,x) */
int j = 2*d*(i / d) + (i % d);
```

What I thought is to shift left upper 32 - x bits of i.
For example the following i with x=5:
1010 1010 1010 1010 
will become: 
**0101 0101 010**0 1010 
Is there an assembly command for that? How can I perform this operation fast?

Comment: You should be using `unsigned`, not `int`. Your example has undefined behavior with signed values (overflow).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

divisions are slow:

```
int m = (1 << x) - 1;
int j = (i << 1) - (i & m);
```

**update**:

or probably faster:

```
int j = i + (i & (~0 << x));
```

Comment: Very good. I completely missed the mathematical aspect that gives the best optimisation there.

Answer (score 5):

x86 32bit assembly (AT&T syntax):

```
/* int MaskedShiftByOne(int val, int lowest_bit_to_shift) */
mov 8(%esp), %ecx
mov $1, %eax
shl %ecx, %eax            ; does 1 << lowest_bit_to_shift
mov 4(%esp), %ecx
dec %eax                  ; (1 << ...) - 1 == 0xf..f (lower bitmask)
mov %eax, %edx
not %edx                  ; complement - higher mask
and %ecx, %edx            ; higher bits
and %ecx, %eax            ; lower bits
lea (%eax, %edx, 2), %eax ; low + 2 * high
ret
```

This should work both on Linux and Windows.

Edit: the `i + (i & (~0 << x))` is shorter:

```
mov 4(%esp), %ecx
mov $-1, %eax
mov 8(%esp), %edx
shl %edx, %eax
and %ecx, %eax
add %ecx, %eax
ret
```

Morale: Don't ever start with assembly. If you really need it, disassemble highly-optimized compiler output ...

Answer (score 4):

Shift left by one upper `x` bits.

```
unsigned i = 0xAAAAu;
int x = 5;
i = (i & ((1 << x) - 1)) | ((i & ~((1 << x) - 1)) << 1); // 0x1554A;
```

Some explanations:

`(1 << x) - 1` makes a mask to zero upper `32 - x` bits.

`~((1 << x) - 1)` makes a mask to zero lower `x` bits.

After bits a zeroed we shift the upper part and `or` them together.

Try this on [Codepad](http://codepad.org/AkqN1z9w).

Answer (score 3):

```
int m = (1 << x) - 1;
int j = ((i & ~m) << 1) | (i & m);
```

There is no assembly command to do what you want, but the solution I give is quicker since it avoids the division.

Comment: Beaten to it by a few seconds :) I think mine is slightly quicker though as it avoids calculating `((1<<x)-1)` twice.

Comment: I think the optimizer would take care of that.  Yours is cleaner though =)

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the optimizer. Even though I know compilers can optimise code like crazy, I've been programming for long enough that I still keep hand optimising code here and there. Not all bad though as it does generally tend to cleaner code.

Answer (score 1):

Intel syntax:

```
mov ecx,[esp+4]      ;ecx = x
mov eax,[esp+8]      ;eax = i

ror eax,cl
inc cl
clc
rcl eax,cl
ret
```

Moral: Highly-optimized compiler output... isn't.